# Code Folding with custom Lexer (ScintillaNET)

Tags: c#, .net, lexer, folding, scintilla

The problem is Scintilla control does the folding automatically, which means the folding doesn't work if you do your own lexer.

I'm using this to configure the control if you want to take a look at the code:

https://github.com/robinrodricks/ScintillaNET.Demo

And this explains how to configure the code folder:

https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Automatic-Code-Folding

Said that, I have made my own lexer which means the code folder doesn't work. Does anyone know how to make it work with a custom lexer?

I only want the code to fold if `{` `}`.

(.NET 7 Winforms C#)